# How to respond to PhD offer emails politely

Tags: graduate-admissions, etiquette

So it is the season where PhD offers are doled out (for US universities anyway). I am lucky enough to have received a number of offers via email. These typically comprise of a polite email from a member of faculty, normally the director of postgraduate study (or similar), along with an offer letter attached.

My question is, are replies to these emails expected? I felt compelled to respond with a quick thank you - I wish I could have asked some insightful question about the program but I couldn't reliably find something to ask.

How should one respond to these offers? What about schools that I will not likely attend as I was offered a school I prefer - should I decline at this stage?

Comment: If you know you are not going to accept an offer, please, *do* tell them as soon as possible, so they can pass it on to the next person on the waiting list.

Comment: To piggyback, all of the rejection email suggestions I've seen include a "I have chosen X instead" or similar line. Is there a polite way to let them know that their school is not in consideration even though I haven't yet made a final decision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already know, for sure, which school you are going; simply respond to others by thanking them and telling them that you already chose your school. Something like the following:

```
Dear Sir/Madam, 

Thanks for the offer. However, after extensive consideration, I chose the university X for my Ph.D. 

Kind Regards, 

Your Name
```

Comment: 'Loads of consideration' is quite informal; 'considerable' or 'extensive' consideration would be more appropriate.